# Giardia lamblia cases of infections

Tags: parasitology

I am wondering if anyone has seen a data of Giardiasis (Giardia Lamblia) cases  in different countries on the world? I have found for different diseases and also for 'diarrhoea diseases' in general, but I need especially for Giardia Lamblia.

Any suggestion where I can try to look for this data will be useful.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have or can get access to it, you might try looking in the Incidence and Prevalence database: http://thomsonreuters.com/incidence-and-prevalence-database/

Another possibility is the GIDEON database: http://www.gideononline.com/. It is possible to sign up for a 15-day trial.

For Europe, statistics are available from the WHO CISID at http://data.euro.who.int/cisid/ (select "all infectious diseases", then "Giardiasis").

The WHO does not have any global statistics available on their website, so otherwise you might have to piece together data from individual publications. Some examples:

Thailand, 2005: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/16438174

Germany, 2006: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed?term=19404678

United States, 2006-2008: http://www.cdc.gov/mmwr/preview/mmwrhtml/ss5906a2.htm

Portugal, 2002-2008: http://www.parasitesandvectors.com/content/5/1/22

Quatar, 2008: http://www.parasitesandvectors.com/content/4/1/211

Tajikistan, 2009: http://www.parasitesandvectors.com/content/4/1/195

Ivory Coast, 2009: http://www.parasitesandvectors.com/content/4/1/96

Tanzania, 2011: http://www.parasitesandvectors.com/content/6/1/3

Ghana, 2006-2009: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3170632/?report=classic

Canada, 1999/2002: http://www.biomedcentral.com/1471-2334/5/72

Canada, 1990-1998: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC194172/

China, 2012-2013: http://www.biomedcentral.com/1471-2334/14/25

Ethiopia, 2009: http://www.biomedcentral.com/1471-2334/13/419

Kenya, 2010-2011: http://www.biomedcentral.com/1471-2334/13/243